# How to overload a member function based on pointer vs non-pointer type

Tags: c++

Given the following situation:

```
template <typename T>
class Whatever
{
public:
    Whatever(T &&t): _t(std::move(t)) { }

private:
    T _t;
};
```

When `T` is a pointer type, I need to check the constructor's `t` arg to see if it's `-1` (don't ask), and change it to a `nullptr` before assigning it to `_t`.
**In other words**, I need to overload this constructor for pointer types.

Does anyone know if this is doable?

Note: Even I partial specialize the class on pointer types, I'd want that class to inherit from the above class itself if possible (since the behaviour of both classes is identical except for this), but don't know if that's possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *don't ask* -- that's a bad approach.

Comment: @Marcus: Checking it for -1 isn't relevant as far as my requirement is concerned. It's something I need to do.

Comment: It sounds as if you're trying to specify the template class, not overload the constructor. That is, you don't want `Whatever<anything>` to have two constructors, you want `Whatever<int>` and `Whatever<int*>` to have grossly different constructors.

Comment: Agreed, unless the constructor is itself a template but it would still be argubaly ugly (though I tried that route without success, just to see if it can be done). However, this which is why I mentioned partial specialization on pointer types. If I go down that avenue however I'll wind up with an identical class except for the -1 check (unless I can derive that specialization from the original class, and just have the derived constructor pass nullptr to the base class constructor when it encounters -1).

Answer (score 5):

You can utilize tag-dispatching and delegating constructors:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Whatever
{
public:
    Whatever(T&& t)
        : Whatever(std::move(t), std::is_pointer<T>{})
    {
    }

private:
    Whatever(T&& t, std::true_type)
        : _t(/*initialize _t as a pointer*/)
    {
    }

    Whatever(T&& t, std::false_type)
        : _t(/*initialize _t as a non-pointer*/)
    {
    }

    T _t;
};
```

Comment: You beat me, was about to post this :D

Comment: @POW: Nice. Thanks. Will see if I can run with it after exploring the other ideas mentioned here as well. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could faff about using `std::enable_if<...>` and deal with overload sets. It is *much* easier to **not** specialize the constructor and just do the appropriate transformation differently:

```
template <typename T>
class WhateverBase {
protected:
    T _t;
    WhateverBase(T&& t): _t(std::move(t)) {}
};
template <typename T>
class WhateverBase<T*> {
protected:
    T* _t;
    WhateverBase(T* t): _t(adjust(t)) {}
};
template <typename T>
class Whatever: WhateverBase<T>
{
public:
    Whatever(T&& t): WhateverBase(std::move(t)) {}
    // ...
};
```

The above logic assumes there is additional code in `Whatever` which is shared between the versions using different types of `T` and which shouldn't be replicated.

Alternatively it would be possible to create a custom version of `move()` which does the logic:

```
template <typename T>
std::remove_reference_t<T>&& adjust_move(T&& ref) {
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(ref);
}
template <typename T>
T* adjust_move(T* ref) { return adjust(ref); }

Whatever<T>::Whatever(T&& t): _t(adjust_move(t)) {}
```

(actually, this approach is simpler...).

... and use this in place of `std::move(t)` in the constructor.

Comment: I actually played with that idea and "enable_if", including hybrids of your example. The issue is just slightly more subtle than what I mentioned though, because I also want to separate "void *" pointers from other pointers as well (longer story), and hit a road block no matter what I tried. This is why I'm bouncing the idea off of people here, to see what the possibilities are. Do you know if it's possible to derive your T * specialization above from the class above it. I wouldn't think so but want to rule it out. Note that this entire exercise is to support some legacy code.

Comment: BTW, your suggestion is appreciated (nice approach)

Comment: @mikestz: you can just also specialize/overload for `void*` specifically. You also _can_ derive a specialization from the more general **if** you change the type of the template argument! For example, you can do something like this: `template <typename T> class Whatever<T*>: public Whatever<T> { ... };`

Comment: Thanks for that. Will explore your idea(s) in some more detail (in the context of what I need to accomplish) and get back to you at some point (to let you know if I was successful). Inheriting a specialization from the original is an issue in the general case of course because you wind up deriving the class from itself (resulting in a obvious compiler error). Anyway, thanks for the feedback.